# I have migrated from log4j1 to log4j2 in my project, and facing error: Reconfiguration failed

Tags: log4j2

when I looked in .ksh file, configuration for log42.xml is there

> Error: StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '33909752' at 'null' in 'null'

Answer (score 1):

just do below changes, where lo4j.configuration file path was set:

earlier: `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/complete_path/log4j2.properties`

now: `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/complete_path/log4j2.properties`

change properties file or configuration file location pattern:
from : **-Dlog4j.configuration=file**
To: **-Dlog4j.configurationFile**